# Best Practices for deployments on a 24x7 system asp.net platform

Tags: deployment, web-deployment

We have built an enterprise web application on asp.net platform which is well load balanced across several servers. We are struggling a bit in terms of doing regular deployments as the application has been defined with an SLA of zero downtime.

Any guidance / tips would be highly appreciated for Implementing best practices to support uninterrupted deployment.

Answer (score 2):

My two favorite books that cover some of these topics are Continuous Delivery by Humble/Farley and Web Operations by Allspaw/Robbins.

I think the "easy" part here is to do a rolling deployment where you pull a node out of the load balancer, upgrade it, run smoke tests, and place it back in the load balancer. Different users will encounter different versions of the app, but you get zero downtime.

The hard part is the backend system / database that these web-apps are likely hitting. You basically need to have both old and new schemas available concurrently which is challenging. Look at techniques like the [expand / contract database pattern](http://exortech.com/blog/2009/02/01/weekly-release-blog-11-zero-downtime-database-deployment/) as an approach to pulling this off.

Comment: yes, the application is the easy part but having the concurrent databases is quite challenging especially because its a heavy transaction site.

Comment: the expand / contract database pattern may work purely with table column extensions, etc. but i'm highly skeptical that the same approach will suit where we have logics being changed within stored procs or any additional params being passed to the procs, etc.